# Expected number of $k$-cliques in $G(n, 1/2) \ge 1$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, graph-theory, asymptotics, random-graphs

Let the expected number of $k$-cliques be denoted by

$$f(k) = \binom{n}{k} (\frac{1}{2})^{- \binom{k}{2}}$$

let $k_0$ denote the largest $k$ such that $f(k) \ge 1$.

I want to prove that $k_0 = (1+o(1)2log_{2}n$ and $n = \Theta(k_0 2^{k_0/2})$.

I can prove that $G(m, 0.5)$ has no clique of size $2log_{2}(n)$ almost surely using Markov, but does this help?

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a sketch, the (gory) details of the calculations are left.

Note that $f(k)/f(k+1)=\frac{n-k}{k+1} (\frac{1}{2})^{k}$ which is a decreasing function of $k$. So the ratio is at least 1 up to a certain value, then it is at most 1. So we have that $f$ increases from $f(0)=1, f(1)=n, \dots$ (a certain value), then it decreases.

Given the above, instead of taking $k_0$, we can consider $k_1=\min \{k: f(k)<1\}$ and show $k_1 \sim 2\log_2(n)$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

To show this, use the classic estimates on the binomial coefficients (see the first formula in "Bounds and asymptotic formulas" [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) ) and consider the $k$-th root of $f(k)$. The bounds given in the link imply $f(k)^{1/k}= \Theta(\frac{n}{k} (\frac{1}{2})^{k/2})$

Fix $\epsilon >0$ and show: if $k\leq (1-\epsilon)2 \log_2(n)$, then $f(k)>1$ (hence $k_1 \geq k$) and if $k\geq (1+\epsilon)2 \log_2(n)$, then $f(k)<1$ (hence $k_1 \leq k$).

The proof of the first case goes as follows: if $k\leq (1-\epsilon)2 \log_2(n)$, then $(1/2)^{k/2} \leq n^{1- \epsilon}$. Hence $f(k)^{1/k} \geq Cn(n^{-1+\epsilon})/\log(n)$, where $C$ is a constant. This is bigger than 1 for $n$ large enough.

A similar argument show that $f(k)<1$ for $k\geq (1+\epsilon)2 \log_2(n)$.

Comment: is it ok to work with $k_1$ here and not $k_0$? And this implies $n = \theta(k_0 2^{k_0/2}) as well?$

Comment: The entire first part of my answer is to justify this. In any case, you can use $k_0$ and "switch" the appropriate inequalities. You'll get the same result.

Comment: Many thanks. Does this work to imply $n = \theta(k_0 2^{k_0/2})$ as well?

Comment: Mmmm, I can't see it at the moment (there is a factor of $k_0$ in the big-theta which I don't know where it comes from!). Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not too sure. Basically it's from this paper, Theorem 1(i) http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6466

Comment: Ok, try to use the formula for $f(k)/f(k+1)$ with $k=k_0$ and recall what the definition of $k_0$ tells us about this ratio. I have not checked this works, but it is worth a try.